# A bound for the minimum vertex cover of scale-free graphs

Tags: graphs, reference-request

For a complete graph, the size of minimum vertex cover is $n-1$.

I was wondering whether there exist an upper bound (or an expected value or upper bound) for the size of minimum vertex cover for [scale-free graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-free_network), i.e. such whose degree distribution follows a [power law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_law).

I searched and didn't find anything, is anybody aware of any bounds?

Comment: The term "power law graphs" seems to be not the technical one; try searching for "scale-free graphs".

Comment: Maybe you can try to search independent set and scale-free graph since the complement of a vertex cover is an independent set. I found there are some results, such as http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-319-07401-6_24

Comment: Maybe you can look for this paper also in which they consider the more general class of scale-free networks called PLB networks.
https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.04217